# QGIS fixed ID name with autoincrement in data attribute table doesn't work for the string columns

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression

By following this question:

[QGIS set fixed ID name with autoincrement in data attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392391/qgis-set-fixed-id-name-with-autoincrement-in-data-attribute-table)

I tried to prepare the formula, which could let me increment the very last number in the string.

The `ID` is: `VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.1` and I need the increment like:
`VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.2`,
`VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.3`,
`VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.4`, etc

So far, my formula looks as follows:

```
'VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.' || lpad(to_string(maximum(to_int(right("ID", 3)))+1), 3, '0')
```

but it keeps throwing the NULL value in my data attribute table.

The same is with the following formula:

```
'VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.' ||  lpad("pkuid", '3', '0')
```

and this one

```
IF("ID" IS NULL, 'VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.' || lpad(to_string(maximum(to_int(right("ID", 3)))+1), 3, '0'), "ID")
```

Does anyone know where might be the problem?

How to use the

> `lpad`

function effectively?

[image]

UPDATE:

```
   IF("ID" IS NULL, 'VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.' || 
   lpad(to_string(maximum(to_int(right("ID", 1)))+1), 2, '0'), "ID")
```

After changing the "ID", 3 to "ID", 1 the formula has started to work. Could anyone explain what do these values mean? Considering that they bounded with function right and to_int?

Comment: Sorry, as long as you don't tell us what kind of values you have in the field `ID` (is there alreade an increment number inside this field? If not: what else?) and what kind of problem you get with the formula you present, it is difficult to answer. Can you post a screenshot of your attribute table? Why do you include a `maximum()` function?

Comment: OK, I added the shot. As you can see I need the increment such as this, but despite lack of error the function throws NULL and I am wondering where the problem is.

Comment: The expression should work, even without the `maximum` part. I guess you simply defined the wrong field type. Is the field you want to create formatted as string and long enough?

Comment: You can't convert characters to integer, hence to_int(right(ID,3)) doesn't return anything.

Comment: I've returned to_int with all brackets but it still throws NULL

Comment: `right(ID,3)` returns `P.1` (the 3 characters to the right of the input string) for the first entry - so this can't be convertet to integers

Comment: Does this work: `'VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.' || lpad(@row_number, 3, 0)`? https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6MQZ.png

Comment: No, it still throws NULL

Comment: What value do you expect for the last row (with pkuid=4)? `.../VP.4` or `...../VP.5`. I guess  `.../VP.4`.

Comment: VP.4 as the default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expression expert, but I think the following script helps:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.String, len=50)])
layer.updateFields()

layer.startEditing()
request = QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy("pkuid")
for i, feat in enumerate(layer.getFeatures(request)):
    lpad = f'{i+1:03}' # returns 001, 010, 099, 100, ..
    feat["ID"] = 'VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.' + lpad
    layer.updateFeature(feat)
    
layer.commitChanges()
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you. The answer has been accepted and upvoted, as this approach can be a good alternative. Anyhow if someone could solve it on the basis of the expression builder that would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To do that with QGIS expressions, use a `replace()` function and replace the constant string (everything before the final increment id number) with an empty string. So just the incrementing number is left, regardless how many digits it has:

```
'VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.' ||  
lpad( to_string (to_int (replace("ID", ('VON/FLN/CBF-DU2/A1/VP.'),''))+1),3,0)
```

[image]