# QGIS autoincrement ID for groups

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression

I have an attribute table containing information about area, region, and samples. The table structure resembles the example shown below:

[image]

My goal is to automate the generation of IDs when adding new point features to my layer (similar to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392391/qgis-set-fixed-id-name-with-autoincrement-in-data-attribute-table)). I plan to achieve this using the 'Default value' feature in the attributes form of the layer properties.

The desired pattern for generating IDs is as follows:

- Group the data by the columns 'area', 'region', and 'sample'.
- Identify the maximum number of items within each group and increment this number by 1.
- Pad the resulting number to four positions with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following expression for the default value in the form:

```
"area" || '-' ||  "region" ||'-' ||  "sample" || '-'  || 
     lpad(array_length( 
     array_agg(expression:="area" || "region" || "sample",
     group_by:= ("area" || "region" || "sample"))) + 1, 4 ,0)
```

Comment: Nice! I had the different chunks setup individually, but did not know how to combine them. Works perfectly, thanks!